# Hosting for MVC4 projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I tried searching for a hosting company that would support MVC4 but I couldn't find any - I would like to deploy my MVC4 application online but I do not know a hosting company with good prices.
Could you give me a list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bin-deployed MVC 4 apps should run on any hoster that supports MVC 3.

Comment: That will not help me much :). Let see what happens with MVC4 being in Beta now.

Comment: I don't get your point. Mvc4 will just run on a box with .net 4. You don't need a hoster to explicitly support it.

Comment: I understand now - I used a host in US that explicitly said they do not accept MVC4 applications - I will probably switch to another one.

Comment: @Lbordea might want to clarify what they mean by "support". MVC 4 should run (unless they go out of their way to prevent it). But since MVC 4 is in Beta now, they might be unwilling to help you troubleshoot any issues you might run into.

Answer (score 3):

As @marcind suggested, your app will run on any hosting company which supports .NET Framework 4 and integrated mode for application pool. You just need to include the necessary dlls inside the bin folder under root directory.

You also has a way to deploy and run your app on classic mode but you need a little bit more setup. See this post:

[Running ASP.NET MVC Under IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 Classic Mode : Solution to Routing Problem](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem)

As for your request on hosting company suggestion, here is not a place to ask recommendations on buying products or services.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed Mvc 3 based website by using below tutorial on Mochahost.
Do the Same For MVC 4.(Note : Don't Forget to include necessary dlls).

http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=568